# Why the key function can call the attribute? But I can't directly call the attribute in the console?

Tags: python, key

The complete code is from the example of DEAP package :

https://github.com/DEAP/deap/blob/0ef6c40b4ba24dbbf1591bd97b08857a1fe3376a/examples/ga/onemax.pyHere

And I did a test which the size of both population and individual are 5, and the following statement I typed:

```
>>>MAX=max(pop,key=attrgetter("fitness"))
>>>[1,1,1,1,1]
```

I understand this returned maximum of pop.fitness, however, why I can't directly call this as:

```
>>>pop.fitness
```

and the error occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-74-b9dde7c090eb>", line 1, in <module>
    pop.fitness

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fitness'
```

Why this `pop.fitness` can't be called?

Comment: The `pop` doesn't has a `fitness` attribute been assigned, but I wonder why the `key` function can be able to the `fitness`.

Comment: In this case `pop` is a list. Lists don't have a `fitness` method. Your call to `max` is calling the `fitness` method of each element in your list.

Comment: So, in this case, since the `pop` doesn't has a `fitness` attribute, the `key=attrgetter("fitness"` returns a blank attribute?

Comment: No, it returns whatever `pop[0].fitness` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pop` is a `list`/iterable. The list itself doesn't have an attribute `fitness`. The list contains objects which  each have an attribute `fitness`. `attrgetter('fitness')` creates a function which when called with an object returns that object's `fitness` attribute. `max` uses this function to get the value from the list which it's supposed to order by.

I don't know what your list contains exactly, but it's something like this:

```
>>> pop
[Thing(fitness=1), Thing(fitness=2), ...]
```

These two are equivalent:

```
>>> pop[0].fitness
1
>>> attrgetter('fitness')(pop[0])
1
```

`max(pop, key=attrgetter('fitness'))` is doing something along the lines of:

```
for thing in pop:
    thing.fitness  # here be magic using this property as sorting criterion
```

Comment: In deed, the `pop` list contains just numbers, but without any attribute. Since there is no `fitness` attribute, can I say that the `key=attrgetter("fitness")` returns blank, and `MAX=max(pop)` equivalent to `MAX=max(pop,key=attrgetter("fitness"))`?

Comment: If your list only contained ints, `attrgetter('fitness')(1)` would raise an `AttributeError`! Your list does not contain what you think it contains.